# Passing < or > with modifiers to SendKeys

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

How to send key events <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> in C# using WinForms with `SendKeys`?

<kbd>></kbd> and <kbd><</kbd> are not listed in the Microsoft keys list.

Comment: Any effort made to try to solve your problem?

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn Yes, he posted on Stack Overflow. Give OP some credit, that takes a lot more effort than using Google.

Comment: On some keyboard layouts, `<` doesn't require pressing Shift; on some, it requires AltGr (I think). Do you want to send the Control modifier and the `<` character, or the Control and Shift modifiers and whatever key has `<`?

Comment: [Meta thread about this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212165/still-confused-about-minimal-understanding)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Each key is represented by one or more characters. **To specify a single keyboard character, use the character itself.** For example, to represent the letter A, pass in the string "A" to the method. To represent more than one character, append each additional character to the one preceding it. To represent the letters A, B, and C, specify the parameter as "ABC".
>
> ...
>
> To specify keys combined with any combination of the SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT keys, precede the key code with one or more of the following codes.
>
> ```
> Key        Code
> SHIFT      +
> CTRL       ^
> ALT        %
> ```
>
> To specify that any combination of SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT should be held down while several other keys are pressed, enclose the code for those keys in parentheses. For example, to specify to hold down SHIFT while E and C are pressed, use "+(EC)".

I've not used SendKeys in a long time, but I seem to remember needing to wrap a second modifier key in parentheses to get it to work:

```
"^(+>)"
```

I remember this being somewhat vague in the documentation, and I can't remember the exact circumstances, but if you've already tried the above, then parentheses may help.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - "RTFM" is a bit offensive. That's not how I intended it. MSDN documentation can be tricky to navigate until you learn how. That said, more research on the part of the OP would have been a good idea.

Comment: What's offensive about reading the fine manual? I find it's quite a pleasant experience.

Comment: I've heard 'flabergasting' may be a bit offensive on certain parts of Scotland, @elgonzo. =)

Comment: @ta.speot.is - I've found that the pleasantness of the experience tends to be inversely proportional to the acceptableness of the words to describe it when used in a professional setting.

Comment: I've never used WinForms, but I think you've misread the question or the documentation. `^(+>)` looks like `Ctrl++ Ctrl+>`; I make out `Ctrl+Shift+<` to be `^+>` or `^+{>}`.

Comment: @Gilles - No, Ctrl++ would be `^{+}`. Brackets only go around special characters (think `\ `), and `+` is the special character for Shift. `{>}` is not correct because `>` is not a special character. `^+>` should be correct, but I vaguely recall this not working for me, while `^(+>)` did. I could be mistaken, and I don't really want to take the time to compile it and confirm.

Comment: @Gilles, I didn't want to copy *all* of the documentation into my answer, but the following addresses your question: "*The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to specify the plus sign, use "{+}".*"